# read and write to file in c - compressing matrix

Tags: c, file, compression, bit-shift, read-write

I'm trying to write a compressed bits matrix to a and the read it back.
The writing works great but the reading keeps failing and I dont understand why.

```
    typedef unsigned char BYTE;

    int saveCompressImageToFile(const char *fileName, const int *image, int row, int col)
    {
        FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "wb");
        if (!fp)
            return 0;
        if (fwrite(&row, sizeof(int), 1, fp) != 1) {
            fclose(fp);
            return 0;
        }
        if (fwrite(&col, sizeof(int), 1, fp) != 1) {
            fclose(fp);
            return 0;
        }
        int byteCount = row * col / 8;
        if (byteCount * 8 < row * col)
            byteCount++;
        BYTE *data = (BYTE *)calloc(sizeof(BYTE), byteCount);
        int dataPos;
        int dataShift;
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                dataPos = (i * col + j) / 8;
                dataShift =7 - (i * col + j) % 8;
                data[dataPos] |= (*(image + i * col + j)) << dataShift;
            }
        }
        if (fwrite(data, sizeof(BYTE), byteCount, fp) != byteCount) {
            fclose(fp);
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }
    
    int * getImage_compress(const char * fileName, int * pRow, int * pCol)
{
    FILE* fp = fopen(fileName, "rb");
    if (!fp)
        return NULL;
    if (fread(pRow, sizeof(int), 1, fp) != 1)
    {
        fclose(fp);
        return NULL;
    }
    if (fread(pCol, sizeof(int), 1, fp) != 1)
    {
        fclose(fp);
        return NULL;
    }
    size_t mat_size = *pRow * (*pCol);
    int byteCount = mat_size / 8;
    if (byteCount * 8 < mat_size)
        byteCount++;
    BYTE* data = (BYTE*)malloc(sizeof(BYTE)*byteCount);
    if (!data)
    {
        fclose(fp);
        return NULL;
    }
    if (fread(data, sizeof(BYTE), byteCount, fp) != byteCount)
    {
        free(data);
        fclose(fp);
        return NULL;
    }
    fclose(fp);

    int* mat = (int*)calloc(mat_size, sizeof(int));
    if (!mat)
    {
        free(data);
        fclose(fp);
        return NULL;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < mat_size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            mat[i * 8 + j] = (data[i] >> (7 - j)) & 0x1;
        }
    }
    free(data);
    return mat;
}
```

for some reason the function throws exception in the last line (return mat;) , "Starter.exe has triggered a breakpoint". occurred , what's going on over there? I've tried to debug that code and I can't tell why I can't return this value but I can access the cells in the debugger. any Suggestions?

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: Test `write()` using `2 x 2` image to file & check file using a hex/binary editor.

Comment: you aren't closing the file in every case so there may be unwritten data.

Comment: Multiple problems: 1. missing `fclose(fp)` in case of successful write.  2. `fread(&data, sizeof(BYTE), byteCount, fp)` has an extra `&` before `data`, causing undefined behavior. 3. the last loop has undefined behavior if `(*pRow * *pCol < byteCount * sizeof(BYTE)`

Comment: @chqrlie's comments, and: 4. you are reassembling the bits backwards from how you wrote them — change it in the last loop to `data[i] >> (7 - j)`, 5. when you say `sizeof(BYTE)`, you get 1, but what you really mean is 8 — use `8`, 6. since you are decompressing all of the bits instead of just rows * cols bits, your allocation of `mat` is up to seven ints too small — allocate with `byteCount * 8` instead of `*pRow * (*pCol)`.

Comment: Not a bug, but you should use `int byteCount = (row * col + 7) / 8;` instead of needing those if statements. Also use `unsigned` instead of `int` for rows and cols, to avoid signed/unsigned comparisons. Use `size_t` for `byteCount`, and cast to `size_t` when multiplying rows times cols, or cols times i. For speed, you can add `cols` to a row offset for each row, instead of multiplying for every element.

Comment: @MarkAdler: why can't we reopen this question? I have a gold badge for [c] and you do for [compression] which supposedly allow us to reopen questions single-handedly.

Comment: Beats me. Looks open now.

Comment: edited the problem and the functions, would like yall to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the comments in an answer:

So much wrong.

1. You need to `fclose(fp)` when there *isn't* an error in error in your first function. Otherwise not all of the data will be written. Or maybe nothing will be written.
2. `fread(&data,` ... would try to read the data over the *pointer* to the allocated space! It should just be `fread(data,` ...
3. You are reassembling the bits backwards from how you put them in. Change the reassembly to `data[i] >> (7 - j)`. Or assemble them in the other direction.
4. `sizeof(BYTE)` is 1. You mean 8. Use `8` for those.
5. Your allocation of `mat` when decompressing can be up to seven `int`s shorter than what you're writing. Either allocate `mat` large enough, using `byteCount * 8`, or only decompress rows * columns `int`s.

Comment: I don't understand way the mat allocation can be 7 ints shorter' the real number of cells in the matrix in the first place is row*cols and which I read directly from the file. so why it will get shorter ?
sec of all, shouldn't I read the byte count times char size ? (has 8 bits in it so every byte or char will hold 8 bits from the actual matrix)

Comment: Suppose we have a 3x3 image. Nine pixels. Your `mat` will be allocated nine `int`s. `byteCount` will be two in this case. (Do the calculations yourself.) Those two bytes will have 16 bits. The problem is that your last loop will process _all 16 bits_, and write 16 `int`s to `mat`, when you had allocated only nine `int`s. So the last seven bits processed will write in the memory _after_ `mat`, `mat[9]` through `mat[15]`, which don't exist. This results in undefined behavior, since who knows what's being kept in those 28 bytes of RAM.

Comment: edited the problem and I would like you to take a look .

Comment: Now you're _massively_ overwriting eight times the size of the memory actually allocated for `mat`! Also massively overeading eight times the size of the memory allocated for `data`. You're just writing code without thinking. Think. Then write.

Comment: That should have been a new question. You have wiped out any possible value of the answer. You don't keep replacing old questions with new questions.